# Inequality of measures extending to a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a set, $A_0$ an algebra on $\Omega$, and $A$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by  $A_0$. Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be measures over $A$ such that $\mu (x) \leq \nu (x)$, for all $x\in A_0$. Show that the inequality does not need to hold for all $x\in A$, and provide additional conditions that do extand the inequality.

This is an exercise from H. Bauer's Measure book. My guess is that I have to find some algebra   for which every element has infinite measure (for both $\mu$ and $\nu$), and the inequality is false on $A\backslash A_0$, but I can`t find such an example. He suggests taking $A_0$ as the set of finite unions of half left open intervals in the real line, $\nu$ as the counting measure, and $\mu:=2\nu$. But isn't every set in $A$ infinite in this case?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are sets with finite cardinality.
Take $a\in\mathbb{R}$. For every positive integer $n$, we have that the sets $(a-\frac{1}{n}, a]$ belong to $A_0$ and hence to $A$. Since $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then it is closed under countable intersections and therefore, the set $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (a-\frac{1}{n}, a]$ belongs to $A$. But we have that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (a-\frac{1}{n}, a]= \{a\}$ since $a$ is the only number that belongs to every interval. Then $\{a\}\in A$ and using that $A$ is closed under countable unions, we have that every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with finite cardinality belongs to $A$

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking too much in the countable unions, and forgot about the intersections.